# Animacion de navbar responsive con css

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo una funcion de javascript que hace que me muestre y se oculte el navbar, ahora quiero hacer la animacion del slide al bajar y al subir, pude arreglarmelas para hacer la animacion de bajar, **pero no sabria hacer la animacion de cuando sube**, voy a pasar todo el codigo que tengo hasta el momento

```js
 function responsiveNav(){
        var x = document.getElementById("responsive");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
        }
```

```css
.responsive ul{
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            list-style: none;
            animation-name: nav;
            animation-duration: 0.5s;
        }

        @keyframes nav {
            from{

                height: 0px;
            }
            to {
                height: 72px;
            }
        }
        .responsive-nav li, a{

            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
```

```html
 <section>
        <div id="responsive" class="responsive">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    <button onclick="responsiveNav()">Hola</button>
```

**Otro de los problemas** que se me presentan, es que a la hora de entrar a la pagina, el menu queda abierto, y no cerrado, no se por que sucede esto.

Cabe recalcar que estoy aprendiendo a hacer animaciones con CSS

**Muchas gracias por su ayuda de antemano.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

es un problema que tuve cuando empecé a hacer barras de navegación, también me preguntaba eso, la respuesta es muy sencilla. Hice tu mismo código y lo mejoré un poco.

**HTML**

```
<section>
      <div id="responsive" class="responsive">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
 <button id="btn">Abrir y Cerrar</button>
```

**CSS**
Si te fijas en el CSS, al contenedor del menú `<div id="responsive" class="responsive"> </div>` le puse un `position: absolute` para que el contenedor tomara su espacio (width y heigth) desde la ventana con la propiedad `top: -160px` que quiere decir que estará arriba del margen de la ventana escondido a -160px, después cree una clase `.show` que simplemente cuando es aplicada al div lo muestra desde -160px a 0px que es su ubicación cuando está abierto. Además le coloqué una propiedad `transition: 0.3s ease`para que tenga un efecto suave al expandirse y recogerse (esa es la animación que buscas)

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
button {
  position: fixed;
}
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -160px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.show {
  top: 0px;
}

.responsive ul {
  width: 100%;
}
.responsive li {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.responsive li,
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**Javascript**
Aquí implementé una pequeña lógica para poner y quitar la clase `.show` de CSS en los clicks del botón

```
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const responsive = document.querySelector(".responsive");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (responsive.classList.contains("show")) {
    responsive.classList.remove("show");
  } else {
    responsive.classList.add("show");
  }
});
```

**Te dejo el código completo para que lo pruebes**

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const responsive = document.querySelector(".responsive");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (responsive.classList.contains("show")) {
    responsive.classList.remove("show");
  } else {
    responsive.classList.add("show");
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
button {
  position: fixed;
}
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -160px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.show {
  top: 0px;
}
.responsive ul {
  width: 100%;
}
.responsive li {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.responsive li,
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <section>
      <div id="responsive" class="responsive">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
    <button id="btn">Abrir y Cerrar</button>
```

Comment: Increible! muchas gracias, es lo que yo queria hacer desde un principio y sin usar los keyframes, aprendi mucho, muchisimas gracias Dan!

Comment: No hay de qué amigo! Dale duro y crea muchas cosas ahora que ya sabes el truco! Saludos :D